# How can I tell what is making Elementary Loki slow in my laptop (Intel Core i3, 4Gb RAM)

Tags: release-loki, performance, monitoring

My Intel Core i3 computer gets slow sometimes, since I installed Loki.  I'm quite a fan of Elementary OS and loved the way my laptop's performance improved with Luna and even better with Freya, but with Loki I have a series of lags that I don't know how to solve or replicate.

Considering it has 4Gb of RAM, and it is a standalone PC (no Virtual Host), I'm unable to say what is causing these lags.  The only thing I can tell is that it happens sometimes during Internet Browsing (Firefox, Chrome, even Empathy), and most of the time waking up from sleep mode if I'm gone for a few minutes.

But, noticing that I can watch movies there with VLC, even with HD videos through HDMI, I don't think it's an issue related with the amount of RAM or video drivers.

So, what I really want to know is **what are the tools or steps needed to be followed, so I can narrow the possible causes?**

I'm relatively a noob, so your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend starting by watching something like `gnome-system-monitor` to see if CPU or RAM is maxing out at these times.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation for monitoring @Lewis-Goddard .  I also installed ZRam [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) to see how it goes.

Comment: You can try installing Preload, it will make it a bit faster. Similar to Zram, you can use both of them at the same time. sudo apt install preload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One terminal command you can use is called 'top'. The link is [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/fl/The-Linux-Top-Command.htm). I personally would use that and leave the terminal window open and just monitor it to see what process is causing the issue. This will at least give you an idea to where to start looking.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will begin monitoring my system with that and the link was really helpful.

Also @LewisGoddard suggestion for gnome-system.monitor is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing exactly the same issue.

I had wonderful performance with Luna and Freya. With Loki however I am disappointed with the interactivity problems I'm experiencing.

For example sometimes when I open a new browser tab the mouse will completely freeze for up to 15 seconds until the new page has finished rendering. Even if no other programs are open.

I have an i5 with 4gb of RAM. I have over 2gb free at the moment, so it's not swapping.

Perhaps it's something with the newer kernel?

Comment: I don't really know, but, in these two days of using ZRam and ugrading Elementary had made my overall experience quite good.  I haven't experienced those long lags at all.  I'm still testing (loads of tabs on Firefox and Chrome, with Netflix running).  I will also follow @GiovanniCaligaris suggestion of installing Preload.